# powershell silent install for ruby devkit tdm

Tags: powershell

Am trying to extract Ruby Devkit Tdm package using below command,

```
Start-Process "C:\DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe" -ArgumentList "-o'C:\Ruby-DevKit' -y" -PassThru -Wait
```

but its having 7-zip unknown error. I found in Google for NSIS script which has to perform this and below is the query,

```
ExecWait '"$TEMP\${devkit_installer}" x -o"${devkit_path}" -y /silent /noreboot /nocancel /noicons' $1
```

Is there any similar way to perform silent unzip this using powershell?

Comment: What's the `7-zip unknown error` exactly? Is the file damaged?

Comment: You can install it through Chocolatey (choco install ruby.devkit -version 4.5.2). More on Chocolatey here: https://chocolatey.org/

Comment: @DavidBrabant I can't install using Chocolatey since my firewall rules will not allow to connect outside network

Comment: @vonPryz When I ran that command one pop up window came and giving 7-zip unknown error, there is no message apart from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the single quotes around the folder path in your ArgumentList, `Start-Process` isn't passing them as you would expect. You only need them if you have a space in your path so you can just remove them in this case:

`Start-Process C:\DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe -ArgumentList "-oC:\Ruby-DevKit -y" -PassThru -Wait`

If you just used the [call operator](http://ss64.com/ps/call.html) to run the command it works fine with single quotes, but the installer itself does not wait to finish so the script continues whilst the install is still in process.

`& C:\DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe -o'C:\Ruby-DevKit' -y`

So there's two ways around your issue depending on if you want the script to wait for the install or not.